# Is it safe to save Django secret variables in the settings.py on Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku

Heroku lets you externalise Django configuration, i.e. to put API IDs and secret keys into config vars, that can be later accessed as in `os.environ.get('MYVAR',3)`

It is shown how to do that in [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#define-config-vars).

However, is it safe to just hardcode the secret variables in the settings.py if I am using a private Git repository for my project?

Answer (score 1):

It's safe as long as no one can get into your server files or Git repository, but neither of those seems wise to assume, unless you are even more worried about someone getting into your Heroku account.